# Android | arraylist.size() returning 0 even if it is declared as global variable?

Tags: java, android, variables, arraylist, while-loop

I have a method to fetch all the images uri and store it into `arrayList`. It is declared as a global variable before any method declaration. It has a while loop which fetches the images till the `cursor` has next entry. while loop terminates when there is no item left. Inside the while loop `arrayList.size()` returns 4 which is expected as my device has only 4 photos. But, outside the while loop it returns 0. I can't understand it why.

```
...
 public ArrayList<ImageModel> fetchImages() {
        imageModel = new ImageModel();
       if(!FETCHED || !previousList.equals(arrayList)) {
            uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
            orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED;
            cursor = activity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");
            column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID);

            new Thread(() -> {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) { //Start of while loop....
                    Log.d("FetchImages(): ", " Started");
                    long mediaId = cursor.getLong(column_index_data);
                    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (!list.contains(name))
                        list.add(name);
                    Uri uriMedia = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, "" + mediaId);
                    imageModel.setUri(uriMedia);
                    arrayList.add(imageModel);
                }// End of while loop
                cursor.close();
                Log.d("FetchImages(): ", " Ended");
                Log.d("FetchAlbums(): ", " Ended with list size "+list.size());
                Log.d("Inside of While", "fetchImages: "+arrayList.size()); //returns 4
            }).start();
            FETCHED = true;
            previousList = arrayList;
        }
        Log.d("Out of While", "fetchImages: "+arrayList.size()); // returns 0
        return arrayList;
    }
...
```

The variable array is declared at the top.

```
public class FetchImages {

   
    private static ArrayList<ImageModel> arrayList;
    private static ArrayList<String> list;
...
```

Same thing is happening to another arraylist variable `list`.

Comment: Because it happens in another thread. Your code is not linear.

Comment: so, how do i fix this problem? If i remove the thread from while loop it really decreses the loading time of images.

Comment: take a look at this sample: https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/MediaStore

Comment: I looked into the example. And I figured some thing. Threads don't necessarily share the same variable. They might create their own local variables. This can cause the uncertainity. And it makes sense `list` is null after the thread. But, the function mentioned here returns `arrayList`. And return statement is out of the thread as well. But, that return statement is returning expected results despite the fact that it is outside of the thread and `arrayList` is updated inside the thread.  At the same time log prints `0` and return statement is returning the expected output. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problems arises due to unsynchronous behaviour of threads. Avoid using too much threads.

Threads don't share the single copies of the variables. So, in the `while loop` It has it's own variable where The main variable is 0.